# view SqlXmlCommand.ExecuteCommand() on SQL server

Tags: c#, sqlxml

I am having an issue where I am looking at a legacy application that is using SqlXmlCommand objects to get data from the database. There is an .xsd file that has the tables that are being used, and what fields, their relationships etc. The issue that we are having is it works most of the time, but not all. I am wondering if there is a way to check what is actually being run on Sql Server. I don't have the SQL profiler installed so that option is out.

the code looks like:

```
SqlXmlCommand xcmd = new SqlXmlCommand(DataAccess.OleDbConnectionString);
xcmd.CommandType = SqlXmlCommandType.XPath;
xcmd.SchemaPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"myXsd.xsd"));
xcmd.XslPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, String.Format(@"myXsl.xsl", ReportType)));
xcmd.CommandText = "id[@PK=$PK]";
SqlXmlParameter p = xcmd.CreateParameter();
p.Name = "@PK";
p.Value = Id;

using (Stream s = xcmd.ExecuteStream()) { ... }
```

This blows up at the ExectureStream() with the error:

```
SQLXML: error loading XML result (XML document must have a top level element.)
```

We believe that there is some data abnormality that is causing the xml to not generate properly, and that is why we want to see what is exactly run.

Cheers

Comment: Even if you do not have SQL Profiler installed you can still run server side traces or use extended events. Setting up one of these traces can be a bit tricky. When you have done it once you will definitely use it many many times again. I think that It is worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below two queries, you might need to tweak it a little, but to give you an idea, the first gives you a list of all requests, and the second will give you the detail of the request by its request id (session_id)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests

DBCC INPUTBUFFER (12345)
```

Although I would personally rather try and debug the C# app first and view what's being sent over to the server from the VS debugger before bothering with checking what's being run on SQL Server

Also, `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` might give you something like `EXECUTE dbo.MyStoredProc 'params...'`, to dig deeper, or otherwise a more straightforward query, you can run this

```
SELECT r.session_id, r.[status], r.command, t.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.[sql_handle]) t
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. When trying to debug the code in C#, we cannot find out what the query is. There is no property that will tell us. That's why I am trying to go down this route. i will let you know what I find.

Comment: @ncbl I'm not fam with SqlXmlCommand, but the above queries should give you what you need from the SQL Server side, just need to be sure to run it while the query you want to investigate is executing of course

Comment: Thanks for this mate, it did the trick in the end. Found that the query that was being generated was casting a string to a float - but when our PK got higher than 1 million records it blew up.